# How to find the arccosine in degrees java

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am trying to just make an all-encompassing calculator, but I am running into an issue. While I am trying to find the missing angle using the Law of Cosines, I am not getting the same answer as my calculator.

```
double answer = 0;
else if (solver == 2 && choice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter side length opposite of wanted angle: ");
        double c = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter known side #2: ");
        double b = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter known side #3: ");
        double a = in.nextDouble();

        answer = (Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(b,2) - Math.pow(a,2)) /  (-2 *         (a * b));
        answer = Math.acos(answer);
        System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
    }
```

Without the "answer = Math.acos(answer);", I am getting the proper answer needed before the final step, but then I need the arccosine of that answer. I don't get the right answer. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: What type of variable is `answer` ? also what are you expecting the answer to be, degrees or radians?

Comment: double. And as the question says, in degrees.

Comment: As the denominator gets large your calculation will trend to zero because your datatype only has so many bits it can use to A. represent itself, and B. do math in binary.

Comment: Ah, I missed the caption. My apologies. `Math.acos()` expects radians, and returns radians. look into Math.toDegrees() and Math.toRadians()

Comment: I also tried Math.toDegrees() and I get NaN, toRadians gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Do not edit the question and change the code to the solution. You have an answer below with the solution. Click the checkmark next to it to accept that solution. Reverting question to remove solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives me the correct output, notice the addition of Math.toDegrees():

```
        double answer = (Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(b,2) - Math.pow(a,2)) / (-2 * (a * b));
        answer = Math.acos(answer);
        System.out.println("Answer: " + Math.toDegrees(answer));
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out. I was stumped for about 2 hours for some reason. I was trying to incorporate the Math.toDegrees into the acos. I.e. Math.acos(Math.toDegrees(answer));